# Служить в театре

Tags: грамотная-речь

Навеяно словами  о Марине Голуб: служила в театре имени Чехова. По-прежнему ли нормативно, говоря о работе в театре, употреблять слово "служить"? Или это устаревшее сочетание?

Comment: Мой знакомый сторож (он же дворник) на мой утренний вопрос: "Как дела, как здоровье?" — всегда отвечает: "Да какие дела? Со службы на службу — вот и все мои дела". У нас в России кого ни послушаешь, так все *служат*. Когда же работать то начнём?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, актеры в театрах служат. Это потому, что они - *служители Мельпомены*.
Впрочем, понятие работа=служба не исчезло совсем и в других сферах. Я могу сказать без иронии "Где служите?" не только военному... А уж обороты типа "на государевой службе" вообще становятся популярны в отношении *государственных служащих*.

Comment: У нас я таких сочетаний не встречала. Даже в сочетании со словом "театр"

Comment: Что именно? "Служить в театре" - это легко можно найти в сети.

Comment: Я имею в виду в устной речи

Comment: Интернет в целом - та же устная речь.

Answer (score 4):

Я не раз слышал от известных актеров театра (и от молодых, и от начинающих) это словосочетание — "служить в театре".
Это своеобразный профессионализм, если можно применить такой термин к словосочетанию.

Answer (score 3):

Просто надо знать, какое отношение в обществе было (в России) к актерам театров.
До революции 1917г. называли их актеришками, актерками, катали их на  тройках по ночным улицам, хоронили за оградой погоста — как самоубийц.

Конечно, у артистов сложился своего рода комплекс по этому поводу.
Все театры в губернских городах были городскими либо частными, т.е. существовали на средства от представлений.
Но были еще и *Императорские театры*, в которых актеры получали государственное жалование. Таких театров было немного, и это, естественно, была элита — как театрального искусства, так и общества. И вот когда такого актера спрашивали, чем занимается, он гордо отвечал, что служит в театре, — и все было ясно о социальном статусе этого человека.

Comment: Интересный ответ. +1 от меня.

**Что, действительно, актёров хоронили за оградой кладбища?** Кто-то ещё что-либо подобное слышал? Можно какое-то подтверждение?

Comment: Попробую сам порассуждать. 

Речь идёт о дореволюционной России -- значит, в данном контексте,  о православной вере. Я слышал, что в православии, как говорится, *есть мнение* (не знаю, отдельных священников или всех), что *лицедейство* (т.е. актёрская игра) -- это что-то вроде *лицемерия*. А лицемерие -- грех, потому что это притворство, ложь, неискренность.

НО! Настолько ли это страшный грех, чтобы хоронить за оградой кладбища?

Comment: >Просто надо знать какое отношение в обществе было а России к актерам театров до революции 1917г.   
  
Ой, страсти-то какие... Вы это лично наблюдали или источник назовете?

Comment: Господа Головлевы. А.Е. Салтыков - Щедрин. Там не только про актеров и актерок.

Comment: М.Е. Салтыков -Щедрин, прошу прощения.

Answer (score 2):

Если обратиться к толковым словарям, станет ясно, что служить в театре невозможно, однако, есть и исключения.
В Ростове-на-Дону кинотеатр "Чкаловец" переделан под православную церковь, службы ведутся в бывшем "храме культуры" постоянно, спрос есть. Можно сказать, что "служение в театре" — это попытка некоторых журналистов ввести в обиходную речь новый термин. Есть и возражения, что в театре служат искусству. Тогда следует ожидать "служения" художников, скульпторов, историков, поэтов и писателей... Кто следующий на очереди? Чем Мельпомена лучше остальных муз?
Данное выражение может быть только актёрским жаргоном, не более.
Увы, самый страшный враг родной речи — безграмотность!

"Щепкин Мих.Сем. (1788-1863) рус.актёр. Основоположник реализма в рус. сценич. иск-ве, реформатор рус. т-ра. Был до 1822 крепостным, ***играл*** в крепостном т-ре..."
Советский энциклопедический словарь

Служить искусству можно, работая в театре или играя в театре, что тоже правильно. Для большей убедительности возьмём театр и кино, как близкие виды искусства. Служил в театре, служил в кино? Получается нелепость. Или имеется в виду театр, как здание? Заметьте, что и в БТС Кузнецова про сам театр нет ни слова. Следовательно, служащие исполняют служебные обязанности, что к актёрам не применимо.

"Служить в театре" — перед нами типичный журналистский штамп нашего времени, точно такой же, как и "государевы люди", как можно было сказать в век крепостничества.
Но от чиновника грамотности добиться — только потерять собственное здоровье, ибо там думают вышестоящей головой (возбУждено, завЕдено и пр.).

P.S. Я не стал бы писать ЗЫ. И с грамотностью далеко не у каждого актёра хорошо.

Comment: >Если обратиться к толковым словарям, станет ясно, что служить в театре невозможно...  
  
С чего бы?!   

>Увы, самый стращный враг родной речи - безграмотность!   
  
Вы на актеров намекаете? Так это вы зря.

Comment: Я сказал конкретно, без намёков. Перечитайте. Похоже, вас захлестнули эмоции. "Служение в театре" - в литературном языке недопустимо. Лицедейство не служба ни в каком значении слова. Прежде, чем писать, я сверился с соответствующей литературой.Следовательно, это правило русского языка, а не мнение отдельно взятого человека. 
Кстати, если Вы не журналист, то ваше мнение я уважаю, хотя и не разделяю.

Comment: Уважаемый Гавриленкр Ф.! Почему вы решили, что этот термин кто-то "пытается ввести в обиход"?  Это очень давнее слово (сочетание), совсем не жаргонное, употребляют его не только журналисты. Если обратимся к толковым словарям, то как раз прочитаем, что служащий - лицо, работающее по найму в каком-л. учреждении или в сфере обслуживания (но не на производстве). Более того,с помощью него толкуются другие слова, например капельдинер — (устар.) служащий театра или концертного зала (не работник, заметьте).

Comment: Не оставляет сомнения, что это замечательное сочетания отражает идею именно служения, а не работы (за деньги).  И считать употребление его безграмотностью ...грешно, право.Если слово стало реже употребляться, устаревать (или скорее, это мы стали реже общаться с театром), это не значит, что употребление его - безграмотность.

Comment: >>>Служба...
2.  
Работа, занятия, должность служащего; место такой работы и само пребывание на ней. Поступить на службу. Переменить службу. Оставить службу. Опоздать на службу. Продвигаться по службе. Государственная с. Гражданская с. Получить повышение по службе. Уволиться со службы.    
    
>>>служить...   
5. кому-чему.  
Работать, трудиться во имя чего-л., на благо кого-, чего-л. С. народу. С. науке. С. искусству. С. каким-л. идеалам. С. на благо людей. * Кто служит делу, а не лицам (Грибоедов).

Comment: > P.S.Я не стал бы писать ЗЫ. 

>И с грамотностью далеко не у каждого актёра хорошо.  
  
Могу я узнать, на основании каких словарей Вы этот вывод сделали&?!  
То, что вижу и слышу, не позволяет мне усомниться в актеры в целом и частность - люди весьма и весьма грамотные. А уж среди тех, кто о себе говорит "служу" - есть грамотные безусловно.

Гавриленко Ф., Сравнивая актеров с крепостными, Вы ещё упускаете из виду одну "маленькую" детпль. Актеры говорят о себе это с *гордостью*. А "крепостник" Пушкин был ну просто безгамотным чиновником, когда писал "Служенье муз не терпит суеты".