# Служить на театре или в театре?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Служить на театре" и "служить в театре". Как правильно и почему?

Comment: Повтор вопроса: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10886/Служить-в-театре

Answer (score 2):

Рассказывает **[Павел Руднев](https://thequestion.ru/questions/134647/neodnokratno-slyshal-kak-vmesto-v-teatre-govoryat-na-teatre-naprimer-zachem-vy-togda-voobshe-prishli-na-teatre-rabotat-sluzhit-poyasnite-pravilno-li-eto)** - театральный критик, доцент ГИТИСа, кандидат искусствоведения:

> "На театре" - лексика из девятнадцатого века. Ее употребляют, чтобы
>   подчеркнуть пафос, трепет, приверженность старым традициям. Как и
>   "служить (в театре)".

Современная норма - работать в театре.

[**Макс Ладо**](http://teatr-uz.ru/maks-lado-lne-ponimayu-kogda-govoryat-lv-teatre-ne-rabotayut-v-teatre-sluzhat-ya-rabotayu-v-teatre) (актер московского «Театра на Юго-Западе» Максим Лакомкин):

> «Не понимаю, когда говорят «в театре не работают, в театре служат». Я
>   работаю в театре».
>
> ---

Художественное дополнение:

**[Когда служил я на театре...](http://www.rulit.me/books/bajki-sluzhivyh-lyudej-read-36630-63.html)**

> ...В ту пору, когда я служил на театре... Старые русские актеры,
>   особенно дореволюционной школы, всегда говорили именно так: «Я служил
>   на театре...» Теперь этот речевой оборот подзабылся, из употребления
>   вышел... А жаль! Жаль. Но, хоть и забылись слова, дух театральный не
>   умер. Если «столкнулся» человек с театром, поработал на сцене или
>   всего лишь рядом с ней — он душой с театром навсегда. Проходят годы,
>   десятилетия, но вдруг (вдруг ли?) человек произносит фразу:
>
> — В ту пору, когда я служил на театре...

Answer (score 1):

В 19 веке театром называлось не только здание, но и сцена. На театре = на сцене. А служат оттого, что первые профессиональные актёры в середине 18 века были людьми военными, вероятно, закрепилось служить в армии = служить на театре.

Answer (score 0):

"На театре" в любом контексте - давно устаревшая норма. 
В данном сочетании она частично оправдывается тем, что само понятие "служить" (возводимое к "служить искусству") по отношению к театру тоже устарело. Сейчас говорят "работать", сохраняя служить только как профессиональный жаргонизм. Поэтому как стилистический прием допустимо и "служить В театре" и "служить на театре" (применительно к исторической эпохе). В нейтральной среде - "служить/работать в театре".

Answer (score 0):

**1) Почему предлог НА заменили предлогом В**

Работать на фабрике, на предприятии, служить на железной дороге ―   предлог НА обычно указывает **место  деятельности**, в то время как предлог В чаще обозначает **конкретное учреждение:** служить в конторе, работать в магазине, в банке.

Вероятно,  выражение "служить на театре" вначале было общим указанием на область (сферу), связанную с театром, то есть служить на театре означало "быть  актером по профессии".

Но затем театр стал восприниматься как конкретное учреждение, а не профессия вообще, и мы говорим: работать/служить (кем?)  актером (где?)  **в театре.**

**2) Из Нацкорпуса:**

Приятель тот представлял как бы смежную музу, **служил на театре** лицедеем. [Митьки. Вода и трава (1990)]

**Это современный текст**, но здесь  использован особый стилистический прием. Возможно,  это ирония, то есть насмешливое (но не насмешливо-отрицательное) отношение к изображаемому предмету. Другой вариант ―  перед нами особый (ироничный) стиль писателя в виде смешения разной лексики.